# Jenkins—get "Build Time Trend" values using "Remote Access API"

Tags: time, build, jenkins, remote-access, trend

Is there a way that we can get all **Jenkins-"Build Time Trend"** information *( Build number + Status[success/failed etc] + Duration )* for an application; using the Jenkins remote access API?

Or else I would appreciate if you could post a link of any documentation on how to get information from Jenkins using the Remote Access API. Most of the sources consist of the way of running jobs, but I couldn't find any, which shows how to fetch information from jenkins.

Thanks!

Comment: I could get something done by using this mechanism.  `http://localhost:8080/job/MY-APPLICATION/BUILD#/api/json`  Using this, I will be able to run a loop, call this again and again changing the BUILD# and get information of each build. But it will be great if I have a way of getting all the information with a one call (as a collection) which would reduce the overhead. If you have an idea about such a mechanism, please do help me with this matter. Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use something like this URL:

```
http://jenkins:8080/job/MY-APPLICATION/api/json?tree=builds[number,id,timestamp,result,duration]
```

There's a little more documentation in the root api element:

```
http://jenkins:8080/job/MY-APPLICATION/api
```

I admit to not completely understanding the `tree` parameter. I couldn't find a simple example of retrieving the entire `builds` subtree.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dave Bacher!!! That's what I exactly was looking for!! Thank you very much again!!!

Comment: What unit is that duration? Millis? Jiffis? Microseconds?

Comment: @Danny, the duration fields look like milliseconds in my instance, confirmed by [code documentation](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Run.html#getDuration())

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got the data I need. :)

Answer (score 9):

> I admit to not completely understanding the tree parameter. I couldn't
>   find a simple example of retrieving the entire builds subtree.

You can access the entire subtree of an element by using `[*]` such as `http://jenkins:8080/job/MY-APPLICATION/api/json?tree=builds[*]`

Cheers,

Answer (score 9):

For retrieving ALL builds, use

```
http://jenkins:8080/job/MY-APPLICATION/api/json?tree=allBuilds[number,id,timestamp,result,duration]
```

Note that B is capitalized in allBuilds

Comment: This is real answer as usually you want to use `allBuilds` not just `builds`

Comment: What's the difference between allBuilds and builds? I found there were the same.